# HttpURLconnection connection failure with non .com website

Tags: java, android, hosting

I have been trying to connect my android app to php server.I made a `php` server echo `"Connection success"` so that I could retrieve the same text and display it in `Alertbox` in my android application.I have a website with a `.cf` and the app shuts down every time I connect.
I checked my code found nothing wrong, then I tried a `.com` website, and the app was successfully able to retrieve the html form of whatever was displayed on the page.So is there something that prevents `HttpURLconnection` form connecting to non `.com` websites.

Here is the code.

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
}//takes context as an argument
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "http://www.thejoint.cf/test.php";
    if(type.equals("login")) {
        try {
            String user_name = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);//what does the url object have
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                result+=line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    Log.i("info",result);
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
```

}

Comment: " and the app shuts down every time I connect" is there any error or exceptions? post them in the question if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

> So is there something that prevents HttpURLconnection form connecting to non .com websites ?

you create a regex :

```
String expression  =  "[^"]+\.com" ;
```

and test if your url matches with it :

```
if(your_url.matches(expression)){

 // your url end with .com , do what you want 

}else{

 // your url doesn't end with .com , do what you want

}
```